# Confusion in the definition of differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Differentiability of $z = f(x,y)$ at $(a,b)$ is usually defined as

> The function $z=f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$, provided $f_x(a,b)$ and $f_y(a,b)$ exist and
> $\Delta z=f(a+\Delta x,b+\Delta y)-f(a,b)=f_x(a,b)\Delta x+f_y(a,b)\Delta y+\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon_2\Delta y$, where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are functions of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, with $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ tending to $0$ as $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ tend to $0$.

What bugs me is the term $\epsilon_1\Delta x$. Do we need to necessarily multiply $\epsilon_1$ with $\Delta x$ in the definition? Why can't it be just $\epsilon_1$, where $\epsilon_1$ is a function of both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$?

Answer (score 1):

You may be more familiar with this version of the definition

$$f(x+h)-f(x) = L_x(h) + o(\|h\|)$$

where $L_x$ is a linear map. The $o(\|x\|)$ part is precisely what is meant here by the $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ functions in your formulation of the definition.

Knowing these functions is not necessary to prove the function is differentiable at a point. Explaining why the above formulation is often used. However they must have the $0$-limit property in order to conclude that $f$ is differentiable, which is denoted by the $o$.

In the end, you could also write $\epsilon_1 \Delta x + \epsilon_2 \Delta y$ as a single function. It does not matter. But having only $\epsilon_1$ with the $0$-limit property is not enough as the convergence must be faster than linear, which is enforced by the multiplication by $\Delta x$.